# CSS Solution needed for full width slider

Tags: html, css

I have some problems with a project and am on a thight deadline.

The problem: 
For a webproject the header consists of a full-width background slider and a menu containing the logo and menu items see: (http://d.pr/i/ln6N)

The problem I have is the way it is divided, the red part acts as a slider. The logo has some space between the menu bar.

How would I go about the transparant space arround this logo?
What  I have now is a 100% width div containing the list items and logo on top of it.

I can't figure out how to get the white space on the left and right of the logo while the menu bar is 100% width.

[image]

I hope the image (above) clarifies some as I just don't know how to handle this one.

Thanks in Advance,
- V

Comment: Can you split the menu into menuLeft and menuRight?

Comment: Can you put some code online for us? jsfiddle is a good way

Comment: have you tried `img {margin: 0 5px 0 5px;}` ?

Comment: I got it fixed, dirty tho..

In the image the gray area is one big image with the center cut out so i can place the logo en menu in it.

Ill provide a link when the project is done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed, dirty tho..

In the image the gray area is one big image with the center cut out so i can place the logo en menu in it so there is some transparant space left.